# bash script with case statement

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file called `Namebook`, with following data inside:

```
$ cat Namebook
Kamala Hasan  123
Rajini kanth  345
Vijay         567
Ajith kumar   908
$
```

Then I have a bash script to add a new name in the file `Namebook`, called `add_name.sh`

```
$ cat add_name.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1   $2"  >> Namebook
$
```

Next I have a script to look someone from this `Namebook`, called `look_up.sh`

```
$ cat look_up.sh
#!/bin/bash

grep "$1" Namebook
$
```

Then again I have a script to remove someone from this `Namebook`, called `remove.sh`

```
$ cat remove.sh
#!/bin/bash

grep -v "$1" Namebook > tmp/Namebook    
mv tmp/Namebook Namebook
$
```

These scripts add, lookup and remove users from the `Namebook` file.

Based on the combination of these three script, I created a single script, `all_action.sh`, to perform all said actions

```
$cat all_action.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Select the option
      1. Lookup some one from the Namebook
      2. Add name to Namebook
      3. Remove name from the Namebook

Select the options range of (1-3): \c '

read choice

case "$choice"
in
   1) "Enter the name to lookup: \c"
       read name
       look_up "$name" ;;

   2) "Enter the name to be add: \c"
       read name
      "Enter the number to be add: \c"
       read number
       add_name "$name" "$number" ;;

   3)  "Enter the name to be remove: \c"     
        read name
        remove "$name ;;
esac
```

My question: when I execute the program `all_action.sh`, it throws an error

For example: I am going to run `./all_action.sh`

```
Select the option
          1. Lookup some one from the Namebook
          2. Add name to Namebook
          3. Remove name from the Namebook

     Select the options range of (1-3): \c
1
Enter name to be lookup
Kamala Hasa
./all_action.sh: line no : look_up: command not found
```

Could you please any one help on this ?

Comment: Put the full path to your bash executables. i.e /somepath/look_up

Comment: Hi Raman, All these scripts are available in my current directory, all the files are having executable permission also. for example /home/user/scripts/loo_up.sh

Comment: AS the answer suggests, if the files are in the same directory, you will still need to reference them with e.g. ./look_up

Comment: Where i need to add full path reference?

Answer (score 1):

The commands: look_up, add_name, remove are not found. Put the complete path in your script and specify the Interpreter:

```
sh /home/myuser/myscript.sh
```

or with relative path:

```
sh ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: The interpreter should not need to be specified; the files should contain a shebang that does that themselves.

Comment: Hi apensiv, I added full path name inside the script all_action.sh
For example: full_path/look_up.sh "$name" ;; like this i was added other paths to add_name and remove also. Now its working good.